# Inconsistent results with pkgutil.iter_modules

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out all submodules of a given module in a package.  However when running the function to do this I get mixed results, can anyone explain why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Project layout:

```
/Users/me/projects/project
    setup.py
    /project
        __init__.py
        tool.py
        /projectdir
            __init__.py
            test.py
```

/Users/me/projects/project/project/tool.py:

```
import pkgutil


for importer, modname, ispkg in \
        pkgutil.iter_modules('project.projectdir',
                             prefix='project.projectdir.'):
    if not ispkg:
        print '{}'.format(modname)
```

/Users/me/projects/project/project/projectdir/test.py

```
def one():
    return 'one'
```

This should ideally print out all modules inside `/projectdir` however I get mixed results.

This is right:

```
$ cd /Users/me
$ project
>> project.projectdir.test
```

These are wrong:

```
$ cd /Users/me/projects
$ project
>> 

$ cd /Users/me/projects/project
$ project
>> project.projectdir.one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.__path__` avoids any chance of a relative path for iteration. In your example instead of passing `project.projectdir.` you will be passing `/Users/me/projects/project`.

```
import pkgutil

# import module that will be inspected
import project


package = project
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__, prefix='project.projectdir.'):
    if not ispkg:
        print '{}'.format(modname)
```